# I found this error while I try to run the Command "gradew signingReport" to find the SHA1 key in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, sha1, gradlew

PS C:\Users\mirfa\StudioProjects\tattoo_design\android> gradew signingReport

gradew : The term 'gradew' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- gradew signingReport
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gradew:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: please help me to get ride of this error. This command was working fine whenever I used this but this time dont know why it's heppening.

Comment: try this command 
 ./gradlew signingReport

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo error in your command.

You just have to write `./gradlew signingReport` inorder to get the SHA keys.

Comment: Thank you so much I downgraded the java jdk and set the path and run this command now it's working

Comment: Glad it works for you. Can you please accept the answer if it help you inorder fix the issue. Thanks!